# Should cluster intercepts add up to the overall mean in latent class clustering?

Tags: r, clustering, regression-coefficients, finite-mixture-model

I am working with flexmix package in R to cluster my data (1341 p, 8 observations each). My DV is scaled per respondent, but the overall mean still remains 0. I am using a latent class regression where my model looks something like this:

```
stepFlexmix(WP_spr ~ compostable + biobased + tech | KEY, data = df...).
```

I get to the point where I determine the number of clusters and get coefficients for each of the clusters. However, intercepts of 4 of my 5 clusters are negative, which was a red flag to me. See output below.

[image]

To double check I multiplied each intercept value with the number of people in that segment. I did so for every segment and then added them up and divided by the  number of participants. As I suspected, I got a value -.65, which is **not** my overall mean.

My first question: do intercepts in flexmix represent the mean of the component? If not, can someone explain what is this value? If yes, does anyone have an idea why do mine not add up?

I am self-taught (thus not very confident), so I would appreciated any help I could get.

Best and thanks, 
Milly